# golang type assertion using reflect.Typeof()

Tags: types, go, typeof, assertion

I've tried to identify a struct with string value(name).
`reflect.TypeOf` returns `Type`.

But type assertion needs a `type`.

How can I casting `Type` to `type`?

Or any suggestion to handle it?

http://play.golang.org/p/3PJG3YxIyf

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"reflect"
)
type Article struct {
    Id             int64       `json:"id"`
    Title          string      `json:"title",sql:"size:255"`
    Content        string      `json:"content"`
}


func IdentifyItemType(name string) interface{} {
    var item interface{}
    switch name {
    default:
        item = Article{}
    }
    return item
}

func main() {

    i := IdentifyItemType("name")
    item := i.(Article)
    fmt.Printf("Hello, item : %v\n", item)
    item2 := i.(reflect.TypeOf(i))  // reflect.TypeOf(i) is not a type
    fmt.Printf("Hello, item2 : %v\n", item2)

}
```

Comment: This is completely impossible in Go. A type assertion asserts a compile-time-constant fixed static type only. You have to rework your solution.

Answer (score 10):

If you need to switch on the type of the outer interface{} you wont need reflection.

```
switch x.(type){
  case int: 
    dosomething()
}
```

...but if you need to switch on the type of the attributes in an interface then you can do this:

```
s := reflect.ValueOf(x)
for i:=0; i<s.NumValues; i++{
  switch s.Field(i).Interface().(type){
    case int: 
      dosomething()
  }
}
```

I haven't found a cleaner way, I'd love to know if it exists.

Comment: But this is for determined types only, not custom type. What if i want to do type assertion for custom struct types?

Comment: In my second example, you can reflect on any struct. The "int" is just an example of discovering attributes on the struct as it loops over each attribute.

Comment: I mean we still have to iterate every type we have. There's no way to use type of `reflect.TypeOf` then use it for type casting or type casting by string x.("customtype")

Comment: Nope, you'd need generics for that :(

Answer (score 9):

A type assertion, syntactically, takes a type in the parentheses, not an expression. So it is a syntax error.

You seem to be trying to do a type assertion with a value computed at runtime. Does that make sense? Let's think about what a type assertion is.

A type assertion consists of two things:

1. At compile time: It causes the resulting expression to have the desired compile-time type. The expression `x.(T)` has compile-time type `T`. This allows you to do stuff the expression that you can do with type `T`, which you may not be able to do with the type of `x`.
2. At runtime: It checks whether the value is not `nil` and is actually of the given type, and if not, it causes a panic.

The first part obviously doesn't make sense for a type computed at runtime. The compile-time type of the resulting expression cannot depend on something that is not known at compile-time.

The second one (runtime check) can be done with a type computed at runtime. Something like:

```
if reflect.TypeOf(x) != someTypeComputedAtRuntime {
    panic(42)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Lots of things, but basically "it doesn't work that way". The thing inside the parentheses in a type assertion needs to be a [type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type), that is a type name or a type literal. `reflect.TypeOf(i)` isn't one of those, it's a method call expression. Therefore this is a syntax error. [reflect.TypeOf](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) doesn't "return a type" (which isn't really a thing you can do in Go), it returns a [reflect.Type](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type), which is an ordinary go struct that contains information *about* a type (i.e. sort of a meta-type).

But the more fundamental reason why it doesn't work is because it *can't*... Go needs to know what the type of a variable is when it's declared. Either its type is given explicitly in a `var` declaration, or it's inferred from the type of the initialization value in a `var x = value` declaration or `x := value` short assignment. It is *not possible* for the type to be unknown at compile time. Go doesn't let you write an expression that produces an undetermined type.

The very purpose of a type assertion is to take a value of an interface type (which is a kind of "box" that can hold values of multiple types, or for `interface{}`, any type at all) and retrieve a value of a *specific* concrete type. The value produced by the assertion will have the type named by the assertion, and no other. (In the case of a `,ok` assignment, if the assertion fails, the variable will hold a [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) but still be of the correct type). If you could write an assertion to a type that was known only at runtime, the whole thing would fall apart, so you can't write it — it's an error.

In short, you can't use reflection to do that. You can use reflect to learn what the type of `i` is, you can learn that type's name, you can learn that its underlying [Kind](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind) is Struct, you can enumerate the struct's fields and get the values out of them, etc... all of these are legitimate uses of reflection. But it can't give you back a variable of type `MyStruct` — the way to do that is `i.(MyStruct)`.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for here is a type switch. 
https://tour.golang.org/methods/16

Answer (score 2):

If you can handle the noise and implement an extra method which all the types implement e.g. 'Type() string', you can do something like this:

```
        ve := &ValidationError{}
        nf := &NotFound{}

        switch err.Type() {
        case ve.Type() :
            SendBadRequest(w, err)
        case nf.Type() :
            http.NotFound(w, r)
        default:
            SendInternalError(w, err)
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you can use ValueOf to solve this

```
item2 :=  reflect.ValueOf(i)
fmt.Printf("Hello, item2 : %v\n", item2)
```

Comment: ValueOf() returns a type reflect.Value not the actual underlying type of the interface...